# How can I compile jrtp source to a dll file?

Tags: visual-c++, dll, compilation, voip, rtp

How can I compile JRTP (Jori Real Time Transfer protocol) Library?

Comment: So, what is JRTP? The [Jolly Roger Travel Park](http://www.jrtp.com/) is the first hit I get on Google, probably not accurate. And what did those FAQs/forums tell you to do (i.e., tell us what you have tried and what didn't work)?

Comment: As far as I know jrtplib contains CMake files that generate set of VC++ project. Have you checked these generated VC++ project, maybe one of it create *.dll instead of *.lib. If not then I would modify these CMake files so they can generate *.dll VC++ project file.

Comment: Hello Zuljin,
according to your suggestion I tried to compile from one of the project file I found in the JRTP lbrary folder. when I tried to compile it I got errors that it is not finding the JTHREAD library, then I added the sources of JTHREAD with it. Then it is showing that jthreadconfig.h file is not in the directory. Actually there is none but there is a file named jthreadconfig.h.in. What should I do to get out of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to compile JRTP lib is using CMake. The procedure is described bellow.

**1. Open the Cmake Gui version.

1. Select your source directory such as C:/project/jrtp-3.9.1
2. Select your build dirctory such as C:/project/jrtp-3.9.1/build
3. Press the Add Entry button and add a prefix CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and select the path of
4. the library such as C:/local.
5. Then press the config button.
6. If you want a static library then leave the setting and press the config button again.
7. Then press the generate button.
8. Then go to the build directory and you will see a .sln file. build it using Visual Studio and your JRTP static lib is ready.
9. If you want a dynamic library then before configuring again in the CMake Gui uncheck the JRTP_COMPILE_STATIC.
10. Then the procedure is same and your JRTP dynamic lib is ready.
11. But remember before completing these tasks you have to compile jthread library and place the jthread.lib in the C:/local/lib and the headers of this library in the C:/local/include location. jthread is a dependency of JRTP library.
12. Compiling jthread using Cmake is same as JRTP compiling but it has no dependency.**

courtesy: Jori Liesenborgs (Creator of the JRTP library).

Answer (score 1):

A quote about CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX :

> This variable contains the path to the install directory and defaults
>   to /usr/local on Unix systems. If you intend to install the project,
>   you should set this to wherever you want to install it.

This is a definition from below that would be useful to persons who have difficulties using CMake :
http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Getting%20started%20with%20CMake